# updating a field to a php database with prepared stament

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a field in an existing entry of a table, but I get the following error message:

> Syntax error or access violation,  message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Update = 'update' WHERE User_Name = 'test'' at line 1"

I'm sure the syntax is right for the prepared statements.

```
setupdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE userdetails SET Update = ? WHERE User_Name = ?");
```

...

```
setupdate.setString(1, "friendRequest "+jsonRequest.getString("toadd").toString());
setupdate.setString(2, jsonRequest.getString("user").toString());
System.out.println("executing update");
setupdate.executeUpdate();
```

...

error trace

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1876)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1192)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2051)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1527)
at com.servlet.JSONServlet.doGet(JSONServlet.java:213)
at com.servlet.JSONServlet.doPost(JSONServlet.java:382)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update is a keyword so you need to escape it

```
UPDATE userdetails SET `Update` = ? WHERE User_Name = ?"
```

Comment: Update is the name of a column inside the table. `Update` didn't work

Comment: The space in `"friendRequest "` could also be a factor @ASH

Comment: thats just a string that i'm setting Update too, i removed the space but still not working

Comment: @ASH Yeah but mysql is not smart enough to know that is your intention unless you escape the keyword.

Comment: Plus, try using single quotes instead of doubles for `("user")` and `("toadd")` and `("executing update")` @ASH

Comment: You cannot use single quotes for strings in java

Comment: @ASH add the backticks `\`` and you will get a different or no error at all.

Comment: it needs to be double quotes, gives a syntax error otherwise. this code is running inside a servlet in javaEE if that makes a differance to the syntax

Comment: where should i add the ` exactly sorry

Comment: thankyou the "UPDATE userdetails SET `Update` = ? WHERE User_Name = ?" with the back ticks worked :)

Comment: Great! If you have no more issues you should definitely mark this as the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    setupdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE userdetails SET `Update` = ? WHERE User_Name = ?");
```

instead of

```
    setupdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE userdetails SET Update = ? WHERE User_Name = ?");
```